# How to block a URL using .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, security, url

I'm trying to block this link

```
http://192.168.1.123/index.php?page=php://filter/convert.base64-encode/resource=setupreset
```

from my application using .htaccess file but I'm getting an internal server error.

This is how I'm doing it

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule http://192.168.1.123/index.php?page=php://filter/convert.base64-encode/resource=setupreset$ - [F]

<Files "setupreset.php">  
  Deny from all
</Files>

<Files "\.inc$">  
  Deny from all
</Files
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to check your server's error log for the details of the "internal server error". Whilst the directive you've posted is not correct, it shouldn't result in a 500 error, unless mod_rewrite is not actually installed on your server. (Presumably the two `<Files>` blocks are existing directives and were "working" before adding the preceding rule?)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `.htaccess` to prevent LFI, but validate parameter `page` in PHP.
And if it has to be, capture all `page=php://` ...else you'd miss some of them.
Whitelisting is defintely more effective than blacklisting in this case.

Comment: thanks for pointing to them, i have updated the Answer

Comment: What I've meant is being explained here: https://highon.coffee/blog/lfi-cheat-sheet/ ...while the rewrite rule only captures one of them. `mod_rewrite` might not even be loaded into the server, when it throws HTTP500; would also require `IfModule` directive - and an error message with negated `IfModule` directive.

Comment: That's why I think that it's less effort to whitelist destinations in PHP, than to blacklist in `.htaccess` ...while both is possible. With MVC the rewrites look whole different anyway.

Comment: Yup, .htaccess, WAF ... are useless. This issue must be solved by fixing the backend code

Comment: It's also a performance bottleneck, when these checks run at every single HTTP request.

Answer (score 1):

in RewriteRule, you have to start relative path, not uri.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=php://filter/convert.base64-encode/resource=setupreset
RewriteRule .* - [F]

<Files "setupreset.php">  
  Deny from all
</Files>

<Files "\.inc$">  
  Deny from all
</Files
```